# How to Fix spacing that produce weird symbol inside Code Environment?

Tags: listings

I want to know why there are weird symbols of spacing like this (at the left side for the GLSL code) :

[image: 1]

This is the code that you can check and reproduce:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{9}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{9}  
\usepackage{color}
\newcounter{bash}
\makeatletter


\newcommand{\lstlistbashname}{List of Julia Codes}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofbash{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistbashname
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lop}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{bash}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Julia Code}%
    \let\c@lstlisting=\c@bash
    \let\thelstlisting=\thebash
    %\xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}%
    \lstset{language=bash,
        keywordstyle=\sffamily\ttm,
        basicstyle=\sffamily\ttm,
        numbersep=5pt,
        frame=tb,
        columns=fullflexible,
        backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},
        linewidth=0.95\linewidth,
        xleftmargin=0.05\linewidth,
        breaklines=true,
        captionpos=b,
        #1}}
{}
\makeatother




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{bash}[caption={Bash}]
    sudo -i
    
\end{bash}

\begin{bash}[caption={GLSL}]
    const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
    #version 330 core
    in vec2 position;
    in vec3 color;
    in vec2 texcoord;
    out vec3 Color;
    out vec2 Texcoord;
    uniform mat4 trans;
    void main()
    {
        Color = color;
        Texcoord = texcoord;
        gl_Position = trans * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    )glsl";
    
\end{bash}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

How to fix it so it will looks clear no more of that weird symbols of spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are spaces which `listings` considers part of a string, I believe, so with `showstringspaces=true`, they are shown as spaces. That they're at the beginning of a line makes no odds.

You can replace them with invisible spaces at the cost of replacing other visible spaces in strings with invisible ones.

```
\begin{bash}[caption={Bash}]
    sudo -i
    
\end{bash}

\begin{bash}[caption={GLSL}]
    const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
    #version 330 core
    in vec2 position;
    in vec3 color;
    in vec2 texcoord;
    out vec3 Color;
    out vec2 Texcoord;
    uniform mat4 trans;
    void main()
    {
        Color = color;
        Texcoord = texcoord;
        gl_Position = trans * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    )glsl";
    
\end{bash}
```

[image: make spaces invisible in code listing]

Alternatively, you could remove at least the excess spacing,though you'd still want indentation so this wouldn't eliminate the visible characters entirely.

```
\begin{bash}[caption={GLSL},showstringspaces=true]
const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
#version 330 core
in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 texcoord;
out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;
uniform mat4 trans;
void main()
{
    Color = color;
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = trans * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
)glsl";
    
\end{bash}
```

[image: fewer spaces by setting code flush left]

Or you could replace the spaces at the start of lines with tabs and handle the tabs differently.

```
\begin{bash}[caption={GLSL},showstringspaces=true,showtabs=true,tab={    }]
    const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
    #version 330 core
    in vec2 position;
    in vec3 color;
    in vec2 texcoord;
    out vec3 Color;
    out vec2 Texcoord;
    uniform mat4 trans;
    void main()
    {
        Color = color;
        Texcoord = texcoord;
        gl_Position = trans * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    )glsl";
    
\end{bash}
```

[image: visible spaces with invisible tabs]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{9}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{9}  
\newcounter{bash}
\makeatletter


\newcommand{\lstlistbashname}{List of Julia Codes}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistofbash{\bgroup
  \let\contentsname\lstlistbashname
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lop}}%
  \tableofcontents \egroup}
\lstnewenvironment{bash}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Julia Code}%
  \let\c@lstlisting=\c@bash
  \let\thelstlisting=\thebash
  %\xpatchcmd*{\lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}%
  \lstset{language=bash,
    keywordstyle=\sffamily\ttm,
    basicstyle=\sffamily\ttm,
    numbersep=5pt,
    frame=tb,
    columns=fullflexible,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},
    linewidth=0.95\linewidth,
    xleftmargin=0.05\linewidth,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    showstringspaces=false,
    #1}}
{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{bash}[caption={Bash}]
    sudo -i
    
\end{bash}

\begin{bash}[caption={GLSL}]
    const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
    #version 330 core
    in vec2 position;
    in vec3 color;
    in vec2 texcoord;
    out vec3 Color;
    out vec2 Texcoord;
    uniform mat4 trans;
    void main()
    {
        Color = color;
        Texcoord = texcoord;
        gl_Position = trans * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    )glsl";
    
\end{bash}

\begin{bash}[caption={GLSL},showstringspaces=true]
const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
#version 330 core
in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 texcoord;
out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;
uniform mat4 trans;
void main()
{
    Color = color;
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = trans * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
)glsl";
    
\end{bash}
\clearpage

\begin{bash}[caption={GLSL},showstringspaces=true,showtabs=true,tab={    }]
    const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
    #version 330 core
    in vec2 position;
    in vec3 color;
    in vec2 texcoord;
    out vec3 Color;
    out vec2 Texcoord;
    uniform mat4 trans;
    void main()
    {
        Color = color;
        Texcoord = texcoord;
        gl_Position = trans * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    )glsl";
    
\end{bash}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I need the space string on the left to be gone, not good for the eyes.